# How to move HEAD to other branch in Git without checking out files or updating any refs?

Tags: git

I usually do it by `echo ref: refs/heads/new_branch > .git/HEAD`. How to do it properly?

Some use cases:

1. You imported source code from some other location, now want to commit it into Git (but not into current branch).
2. Your `.git` is just a symlink and now you are accessing it from other workdir (I already know about git-new-workdir to do it properly)

Therefore you want to choose manually what parent the next commit should have and what ref should be updated by it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `git` plumbing command for this is

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/existing_branch
```

You cannot go into detached head state (it needs a ref, not a SHA).  However you can switch to an nonexisting ref (aka. unknown branch).  To prevent that, perhaps use following `git alias`:

```
git config --global alias.switch '!f() { git show-ref --heads --verify "refs/heads/$1" && git symbolic-ref -m "switch to branch $1 not touching workdir" HEAD "refs/heads/$1"; }; f'
```

Then you can use it like `git switch existing_branch`.  Please note, that you need option `-m` to see an entry in `git reflog`, this is usually what you want.

Notes:

- `git reflog HEAD` shows the ref log of `HEAD` (you will see the comment given at option `-m` again).  The full file (which includes before-after SHAs in case you want to find some lost commit) is stored at `$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/logs/HEAD` (for `HEAD`)
- `git show-ref --heads` lists all refs you can use on the RHS.  As shown in the `alias` you can use it with `--verify` to check if an argument is a proper (existing) ref (aka. branch).
- Beware: `git symbolic-ref` can point to any other ref like `refs/tags/` or `refs/remotes/` or even inside packed refs.  This is probably not what you want, hence the alias restricts this to `refs/heads/`.

Answer (score 4):

`git reset --soft $branch_to_make_HEAD`

`man git reset` docs on the `--soft` option:

> Does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all (but resets
>   the head to `<commit>`, just like all modes do). This leaves all your
>   changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put it.

Comment: This changes the ref `HEAD` currently points to. It will also only set parent for the next commit, not the ref to update. I want: 1. no spolied current ref, 2. setting parent for next commit, 3. setting ref that will be updated by commit.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -B existing_or_new_branch # HEAD by default
git reset       existing_branch@{1}    # or anywhere else for a new_branch
```

Comment: Is it equivalent to `git checkout HEAD -B new_branch`?

Comment: Is there really `-B` in `git branch`? It is an option of `git checkout`.

Comment: Sorry I kept the wrong command when reducing to just one - fixed.

Comment: `git checkout -B existing_or_new_branch` updates the ref of `existing_or_new_branch` to `HEAD`, while `echo ref: refs/heads/new_branch > .git/HEAD` does not have this sideffect.  So it goes one step too far, I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks @Tino I've updated my answer. It's now made of two commands and not just one :-(

Answer (score -1):

You don't. `HEAD` is a symbolic reference that shall always point to the currently checked-out commit, i.e. what is in your working copy.
You should never manipulate refs manually -- and only use plumbing commands to mess with them if you really know what you are doing.

This might be a case of [the XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) -- i.e. you think you know how to solve your problem and ask for help with that way, but there might be a better way to do it (only no one can tell you because you didn't ask about your actual problem). I might be wrong about that though :D

Comment: It is often needed when I do tricky things with Git (also involving `commit-tree` and `update-ref`). I want to edit history and refs in some places without lengthy checking files out and then checking them back.

Comment: I often want to change HEAD manually when something (for example, other version control system) updates my working copy. I only need to tell Git it's new branch already without allowing Git to write files in workdir.

Comment: if you only want to create a new branch, `git checkout -b BRANCHNAME` will do that without touching the working copy

Comment: And if I want to commit to other (non-current) branch without touching working directory (external program has switched the working directory to that branch)? My way: 1. change .git/HEAD to point to other branch; 2. `git reset --mixed` -- fixup the index; 3. `git add` and `git commit`.

Comment: that is exactly what switching branches (`branch`+`checkout` or `checkout -b`) is for: 1. `git checkout -b NEWBRANCH`, 2. `git add` (possibly with `-A` switch to add deletions) and `git commit`

Comment: @NevikRehnel "HEAD is a symbolic reference that shall always point to the currently checked-out commit"... most of the time... except when it's not. Which is probably a lot more often then one might think. It's called a `detached HEAD`. However, I do agree it sounds like the original question sounds like the wrong approach to things...

Comment: @twalberg: a detached HEAD is when `HEAD` is not a symbolic reference pointing to a branch, but instead pointing directly to a commit. while that part of the sentence might have been imprecise, `HEAD` shall always point to the currently checked-out commit, directly or via a branch reference

Comment: @NevikRehnel `HEAD` will point to the last commit that was checked out as a whole, either as a symbolic ref to a branch head or as an SHA for a specific commit. However, due things like `git checkout <some_other_commit> -- <some_file>`, `git reset <some_other_commit> -- <some_file>` and many other possible scenarios, what is currently "checked out" may not match `HEAD` at all, nor even any existing commit... Regardless, the commit represented by `HEAD` will still be the parent of any new commit made.

Comment: "repo download" is one example of the commands after which git needs to be rectified like this.

Comment: Downvoted.  Because there are billions of proper usecases more than the original author thought of.  For example is this problem exactly there if you want to get rid of a not neccessary bare repository in deployment or presentation usecases, where you have to switch the presentation branch (read: HEAD) while not touching, ever, the currently checked out work repo.  So I need the proper solution for this problem, too, and "You don't" is really not helpful.